# ObjectListView in closed-source program to sell

Tags: licensing, objectlistview

Is it possible to use [ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/objectlistview.aspx), which uses the GPL v3 license, legally in a closed-source program that will be sold?

If so, what has to be done to make sure to not violate the license?

Comment: While I don't have a specific answer, it may be wise to just ask the author directly. He may make it available under another license for you.

Comment: Ok, I sent him an email.  Hopefully he'll respond, and wishfully he'll let me use it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ObjectListView.aspx) has a GPL license so that it is usable by all free software.

Commercial licenses are available, with payment being related to the size of the organisation that wants the licenses.

If you cannot afford *any* license, we can still work something out. I've never denied a commercial license to anyone who wanted one.