# A good listview component for C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Does anyone know of a good listview component other than the one included with Visual Studio (as it looks kinda boring)?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46738654/7809801) is similar question answered

Answer (score 3):

Devexpress are good too. http://devexpress.com

Comment: Same here, however I think Infragistics offer a better ListView component.

Comment: I don't know about Infragistics or Telerik, but I know for a fact that DevExpress' XtraGrid is awesome... if you're willing to pay for it

Comment: DevExpress and Telerik has better documentation IMHO.

Comment: Devexpress does NOT offer a listview control.

Answer (score 1):

(Quick edit missed the Winforms bit).  For Winforms controls, I'd recommend [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify the look of your form and controls try [DotNetSkin](http://www.dotnetskin.net/). You can modify controls from existing windows themes or your own controls by modifying it.

Answer (score 1):

You may try [Better ListView](http://www.componentowl.com/).

[image]

It has native look and feel. It also supports many nice features, like hierarchical items, multi-column sorting, data binding, three-state check boxes... the list goes on :-)

It is *not* a ListView wrapper, but self-contained control so it fixes all inherent flaws of .NET ListView (these are enumerated on ComponentOwl's website).

Answer (score 1):

If you want a free ListView, you should try [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html), it has a LOT of features.
You better be careful about the license if you want to use it in a commercial product though. See these answers for more information about the license: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298321/objectlistview-in-closed-source-program-to-sell) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552196/a-free-control-like-objectlistview/3552331#3552331).

Answer (score 1):

Take into account the 10Tec iGrid control:

[image: C# ListView replacement]

Its main features are:

- Multi-column sorting with indication in column headers.
- Grouping and autofilter are also available.
- "Subitems" (cells) can be edited.
- Rows can have different heights.
- Rows/cells can be formatted dynamically easily.
- Built-in incremental search.
- TreeListView mode.
- No flickering and fast work with 100'000+ rows.

To find out more, start from reading this article:

[Editable ListView Replacement](http://10tec.com/articles/editable-listview-replacement.aspx)

See also other cross-referenced articles on the site.